# Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x=\infty \implies \exists x_0 \in [0,1] \ \text{s.t} \ f(x_0)>1$

Tags: limits, analysis, definite-integrals, solution-verification

Let $f:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous and nonnegative function. Show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x=\infty \iff\exists x_0 \in [0,1] \ \text{s.t} \ f(x_0)>1$$
I'm only interested in the $\implies$ implication: my textbook solves this problem in a different way, using the fact that in these hypothesis there exists $x_0 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_0)=\max_{x\in[0,1]} f(x).$

I've come up with another solution, can someone check if my solution is correct as well?

My attempt: by hypothesis $f$ is continuous in $[0,1]$, so $f^n$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ as well; hence, for the mean value theorem for integrals, there exists $x_0\in[0,1]$ such that
$$\int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x=[f(x_0)]^n$$
Taking the limit on both sides
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x=\lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x_0)]^n$$
But by hypothesis the limit on the left and side of the latter equality is $+\infty$, so it is
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} [f(x_0)]^n=+\infty$$
This is possible if and only if $f(x_0)>1$, so the implication is proved.

I have another question: by applying the definition of limit for the hypothesis $\int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x \to \infty$ for $n\to\infty$ I have that for all $K>0$ there exists $n_K \in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n \geq n_K \implies \int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x >K$, does $K$ depends on $n$ as well? I believe yes, because for different $n$s I obtain different integrals and so for them to be greater than $K$ the presence of different $n$s in the integrand is relevant. Am I correct or wrong? If I'm correct and there is this dependence, how can I deduce it from the logic of the problem? Is there a $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ implied in the text of the problem before the limit of the integral? Thank you.

Comment: Hint: assume by contradiction that $f\le 1$ in $[0,1]$. What does it imply?

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Thanks for the observation, I think you're right but I'm not fully convinced though, because I've deduced that the limit of $[f(x_0)]^n$ is $+\infty$ from the fact that it is equal to a limit that is $+\infty$ by hypothesis; so, in some sense, this should bypass the fact that I don't know the behaviour of $x_{0,n}$ as $n\to\infty$. What do you think? Can this save the proof?

Comment: @ZaWarudo This proof could be a one-liner with the DCT. Did you choose an **extra** hard way on purpose to solve this?

Comment: @vitamind maybe, but that assumes the OP is already familiar with Lebesgue integration (which may or may not be the case). Also, DCT is equivalent to a nuclear missile for solving such a simple problem (and it is always good to think of alternative solutions).

Comment: @user580918 Thanks for your comment but I asked the OP. You bring arguments which I agree with. That's why I asked the OP if he did not choose the DNT on purpose. Furthermore I never said it's not good to think of alternative solutions. (Also I choose the easiest and fastest theoerem which comes to my mind unintentionally. Observing that $f(x)\le 1$ is bounded  is absolutely trivial which at least for me implies that the DNT probably is the fastest option.)

Comment: @vitamind: The exercises is taken from a first course in calculus (without the presence Lebesgue integral), so I think is intended to be solved without it. Thanks the same for your suggestion!

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Ok, I think that my mistake is that I'm not seeing how the possibilities (like the one you've mentioned) can be possible, because I believed that the condition on the limit of the integral exclude those possibilities; I believed this because if $f(x_{0,n})=1+\frac{1}{n}$ then $\int_0^1 \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n dx=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \to e$ as $n \to \infty$ and so my hypothesis is not verified, so I'm not in the case I'm studying (because my hypothesis wants the integral to tend to $+\infty$).
What am I missing?

Comment: Ok I was mistaken (I misinterpreted your reasoning). Once you fix the $x_0$ to $x_{0,n}$, then yes absolutely, $\lim [f(x_{0,n})]^n=\lim\int f^n = \infty$, so yes eventually, all these points are larger than $1$. I deleted my previous erroneous comments, but my answer to your second question stays the same: $K$ doesn't depend on anything as seen from how the definition starts "for every $K>0$......."

Comment: @peek-a-boo: Ok, thanks for your time! And thanks for answering the other question as well!

Comment: @StefanoCiaci: Thanks for your hint, I've tried this: the negation of $\exists x_0 \in [0,1]$ s.t. $f(x_0) >1$ is $\forall x\in[0,1], f(x) \leq 1$, so assuming this latter assumption being by hypothesis $0 \leq f(x)$ and being the $n$-th power is increasing in the posives, it follows that $0 \leq [f(x)]^n \leq 1$ and then $\int_0^1 [f(x)]^n dx \leq \int_0^1 1\text{d}x=1$. So taking the limit both sides I would get $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 [f(x)]^n \text{d}x \leq 1$, a contradiction with the assumption $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1[f(x)]^n \text{d}x = +\infty$. Is this correct? Thank you.

Comment: @ZaWarudo precisely. Your argument is correct.